# Counting all unique strings in a data frame containing strings and numeric values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a number of large data frames which has the occasional string value and I would like to know what the unique string values are (ignoring the numeric values) and if possible count these strings.

```
df <- data.frame(1:16)
df$A <- c("Name",0,0,0,0,0,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,NA_real_,NA_real_,16,16)
df$B <- c(10,0,"test",0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16,16)
df$C <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)

   X1.16    A    B  C
1      1 Name   10 10
2      2    0    0 12
3      3    0 test 14
4      4    0    0 16
5      5    0   12 10
6      6    0   12 12
7      7   12   12 14
8      8   12   12 16
9      9    0    0 10
10    10   14   14 12
11    11 <NA> <NA> 14
12    12   14   14 16
13    13 <NA>   16 10
14    14 <NA>   16 12
15    15   16   16 14
16    16   16   16 16
```

I know I can use the count function in dplyr but I have too many unique numeric values so this is not a great solution. In the code below I was able to filter my data so to only retain rows that contain an alphabetical character (although this isn't a solution either).

```
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., pattern = "[:alpha:]")))

  X1.16    A    B  C
1     1 Name   10 10
2     3    0 test 14
```

My desired output would be something to the effect of:

```
Variable    n 
"Name"      1 
"test"      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the string value with `grep` and count them using `table` :

```
stack(table(grep('[[:alpha:]]', unlist(df), value = TRUE)))[2:1]
```

---

If you want a `tidyverse` answer you can get the data in long format, keep only the rows with characters in it and `count` them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = as.character)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  filter(grepl('[[:alpha:]]', value)) %>%
  count(value)

#  value     n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 Name      1
#2 test      1
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ronak and @akrun above beat me to the punch, my solution is very similar - with an extension if you want a count within columns

```
# Coerce to tibble for ease of reading
df <- df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = as.character))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  summarise(Variable = str_subset(value, "[:alpha:]")) %>% 
  count(Variable, sort = TRUE)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Variable     n
  <chr>    <int>
1 Name         1
2 test         1

# str_subset is a convenient wrapper around filter & str_detect
```

Add some extra words to test

```
# Test on extra word counts - replace 12 and 14 with words
df2 <- df
df2[df2 == 12] <- 'Name'
df2[df2 == 14] <- 'test'
df2

df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  summarise(Variable = str_subset(value, "[:alpha:]")) %>% 
  count(Variable, sort = TRUE)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Variable     n
  <chr>    <int>
1 Name        12
2 test        10
```

If you want counts by column

```
df2 %>% 
  select(-1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'col') %>% 
  group_by(col) %>% 
  summarise(Variable = str_subset(value, "[:alpha:]")) %>% 
  count(col, Variable)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   col [3]
  col   Variable     n
  <chr> <chr>    <int>
1 A     Name         3
2 A     test         2
3 B     Name         4
4 B     test         3
5 C     Name         4
6 C     test         4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `filter` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   select(-1) %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>% 
   filter(across(everything(), ~ str_detect(., '[:alpha:]')) %>% reduce(`|`)) %>%
   pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
   filter(str_detect(value, '[:alpha:]')) %>%
   count(value)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  value     n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 Name      1
#2 test      1
```